# Does the filter unique slow down things?

Tags: angularjs

For example we iterate over a collection.

```
ng-repeat="thing in things | unique:'thing.name'"
```

Would you say that there is a better solution than this? 
I mean we could filter that data on the server side to make it unique right?

I'm just concerned about the performance of unique.

could someone tell something about best practice? 
If the question is unclear: Would you use unique when you got the chance to do that operation on the server side?

Comment: If you never need the non-uniques and the data 'should' not contain it, then do it server side

Comment: may be `$scope.uniqueThings = $filter('unique')($scope.things, 'name');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you should do it on a backend side when possible.

This is not the `unique` performance question but a question of the network load which is in my opinion more important. You are sending the data which could be reduced in size - this is already a lose.

Comment: Ok and how about unique if the network load doesn't matter ?

Comment: Well, network load is the weakest part, especially for the mobile. RAM (which will be used for the filter) is sooooo much faster than network data transmission. If you don't care about network then you should not care about the data processing as well. This really depends on the amount of data, so I would say when you experience a problem with performance on the frontend with exactly this filter you can think of moving it to the backend or the other way round. Modern clients are powerful enough to process usual datasets, so if your dataset is less than 1-10k you should not care.